# BroadcastReceiver OnReceive not called when returning from StartActivity(ActivityFlags.NewTask)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
   private Activity _activity;
   private IntentFilter _intentFilter;

   public MyBroadcastReceiver(Activity activity)
   {
      _activity = activity;
      _intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
      //setup IntentFilter...
   }

   public void OnReceive(Intent intent)
   {
      if(intent.Action != "<expected intent>")
         return;

      if(intent.GetStringExtra("<extra>") == "<expected value>")
      {
         Intent launchIntent = new Intent();
         launchIntent.SetClassName("<packagename>", "<activityname>");
         launchIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
         _activity.StartActivity(launchIntent);
      }
   }

   public void OnResume()
   {
      _activity.RegisterReceiver(this, _intentFilter);

      SendBroadcast(); //private method which sends a broadcast intent
   }

   public void OnPause()
   {
      _activity.UnregisterReceiver(this);
   }
}
```

I register the receiver in OnResume() and send a broadcast intent with SendBroadcast which is supposed to be responded with *expected intent*. When receiving *expected intent* and the *extra* has a specific value then I launch another activity. Since my application is backgrounded OnPause is called. The launched activity can return anytime bringing my application back and therefore OnResume is called.

**But when my application is brought back to foreground from the launched activity closing, then MyBroadcastReceiver does not receive any broadcasts, however I can confirm that broadcasts are definitely sent by looking into adb logs.**

Strangely, when I go to the home screen and reopen my application everything works as expected. I send the broadcast "request" and OnReceive is called as expected. It seems like the BroadcastReceiver is not properly registered when resuming from another launched activity.

Am I handling registering wrong? Or am I not supposed to launch another activity in OnReceive? Any other clues on what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
Apparently it does not work when LaunchMode of the activity is set to SingleInstance.

Comment: You could mark your solution as the answer. It'll be beneficial for other community members who have similar questions.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error message, that I can accept my own answer only after 2 days.